# Horizontal Center Radio Button in Table

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm not what happening but here is my HTML;

```
<tr id='javatbd158311X2059X38315A008' class='array2 answers-list radio-list'>
  <td class="answer_cell_003 answer-item radio-item">
  <label class="hide read" for="answer158311X2059X38315A008-3">Neither agree nor disagree</label>
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="158311X2059X38315A008" value="3" id="answer158311X2059X38315A008-3" title="Neither agree nor disagree" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to center-align the radio button but just stays on the left. So far I have tried things like;

```
table td .radio { text-align:center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; border:1px solid red;}
table tr td { text-align:center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; border:1px solid red;}
```

It will acknowledge the `border` property. and display a red border, so I know it's being referenced correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE; MORE CODE

```css
table td .radio { border:1px solid red;display: block;margin:0 auto;}
    table tr td { text-align:center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
 <table class="question subquestions-list questions-list " summary="An array with sub-question on each line. The answers are contained in the table header. ">
  <colgroup class="col-responses">
  <col class="col-answers" width="50%%" />
 <col class="odd" width="10%" />
 <col class="even" width="10%" />
 <col class="odd" width="10%" />
 <col class="even" width="10%" />
 <col class="odd" width="10%" />
  </colgroup>
  <thead><tr class="dontread">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <th>Strongly agree</th>
  <th>Agree</th>
  <th>Neither agree nor disagree</th>
  <th>Disagree</th>
  <th>Strongly disagree</th>
 </tr></thead>
  
 <tbody>
 
  <tr id='javatbd158311X2059X38315A008' class='array2 answers-list radio-list'>
  <th class="answertext">
 a. One.<input type="hidden" name="java158311X2059X38315A008" id="java158311X2059X38315A008" value="" />
  </th>
    <td class="answer_cell_001 answer-item radio-item">
 <label class="hide read" for="answer158311X2059X38315A008-1">Strongly agree</label>
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="158311X2059X38315A008" value="1" id="answer158311X2059X38315A008-1" title="Strongly agree" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)" />
  </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_002 answer-item radio-item">
 <label class="hide read" for="answer158311X2059X38315A008-2">Agree</label>
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="158311X2059X38315A008" value="2" id="answer158311X2059X38315A008-2" title="Agree" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)" />
  </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_003 answer-item radio-item">
 <label class="hide read" for="answer158311X2059X38315A008-3">Neither agree nor disagree</label>
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="158311X2059X38315A008" value="3" id="answer158311X2059X38315A008-3" title="Neither agree nor disagree" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)" />
  </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_004 answer-item radio-item">
 <label class="hide read" for="answer158311X2059X38315A008-4">Disagree</label>
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="158311X2059X38315A008" value="4" id="answer158311X2059X38315A008-4" title="Disagree" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)" />
  </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_005 answer-item radio-item">
 <label class="hide read" for="answer158311X2059X38315A008-5">Strongly disagree</label>
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="158311X2059X38315A008" value="5" id="answer158311X2059X38315A008-5" title="Strongly disagree" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)" />
  </td>
 </tr>
 
 
  <tr id='javatbd158311X2059X38315A603' class='array1 answers-list radio-list'>
  <th class="answertext">
 b. Two.<input type="hidden" name="java158311X2059X38315A603" id="java158311X2059X38315A603" value="" />
  </th>
    <td class="answer_cell_001 answer-item radio-item">
 <label class="hide read" for="answer158311X2059X38315A603-1">Strongly agree</label>
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="158311X2059X38315A603" value="1" id="answer158311X2059X38315A603-1" title="Strongly agree" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)" />
  </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_002 answer-item radio-item">
 <label class="hide read" for="answer158311X2059X38315A603-2">Agree</label>
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="158311X2059X38315A603" value="2" id="answer158311X2059X38315A603-2" title="Agree" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)" />
  </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_003 answer-item radio-item">
 <label class="hide read" for="answer158311X2059X38315A603-3">Neither agree nor disagree</label>
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="158311X2059X38315A603" value="3" id="answer158311X2059X38315A603-3" title="Neither agree nor disagree" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)" />
  </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_004 answer-item radio-item">
 <label class="hide read" for="answer158311X2059X38315A603-4">Disagree</label>
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="158311X2059X38315A603" value="4" id="answer158311X2059X38315A603-4" title="Disagree" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)" />
  </td>
    <td class="answer_cell_005 answer-item radio-item">
 <label class="hide read" for="answer158311X2059X38315A603-5">Strongly disagree</label>
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="158311X2059X38315A603" value="5" id="answer158311X2059X38315A603-5" title="Strongly disagree" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)" />
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: In your example code, adding a red border to both `.radio` and `table tr td` is a bit confusing. Differently-coloured borders might make it a bit clearer what’s going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make radio button as a block element.

`display:block`

```css
table td .radio { border:1px solid red;display: block;margin:0 auto;}
table tr td { text-align:center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr id='javatbd158311X2059X38315A008' class='array2 answers-list radio-list'>
  <td class="answer_cell_003 answer-item radio-item">
  <label class="hide read" for="answer158311X2059X38315A008-3">Neither agree nor disagree</label>
  
  <input class="radio" type="radio" name="158311X2059X38315A008" value="3" id="answer158311X2059X38315A008-3" title="Neither agree nor disagree" onclick="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type)" />
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @mike3875 may be you are using `float:right`  you should check once.

Comment: Okay let us check agian

Comment: I check you code and copy that in snippet , It working with your provided code

Comment: and? did it work out? don't forget to put your question as answered @mike3875

Answer (score -1):

give the input display block

```
u can find the code here
 [https://jsfiddle.net/u85mca3d/][1]
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes